# AES Encryption in iphone

Tags: iphone, ios, encryption, aes, itunes

in my iphone app i have to encrypt the text data using AES128 encryption standards. This encrypted data will be sent to the server in the POST request and also the data that will come from the server will be in encrypted form that will be decrypted in the app.
Now the question is, if i implement this behavior in my iphone app and submit it to app store, will apple approve/authorize my app?
All answers will be appreciated.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

[This](http://tigelane.blogspot.it/2011/01/apple-itunes-export-restrictions-on.html) is the most updated information I've been able to find when I googled about the same issue.

Basically you need to obtain a *Encryption Registraton Number* (**ERN**) that you will send through iTunesConnect when answering questions related to using encryption in your application. Mind that I'm not sure this can be done from someone ouside United States but I guess there are no problems.